# Using preg_replace to replace all occurrences in php

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Regex is absolutely my weak point and this one has me completely stumped. I am building a fairly basic search functionality and I need to be able to alter my user input based on the following pattern:

Subject:

```
%22first set%22 %22second set%22-drupal -wordpress
```

Desired output:

```
+"first set" +"second set" -drupal -wordpress
```

I wish I could be more help as I normally like to at least post the solution I have so far, but on this one I'm at a loss.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: It seems your data is URL encoded. If you apply [urldecode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php), you will get `"first set" "second set"-drupal -wordpress`. Do you have actually a space before `-drupal` or should this be inserted too?

Comment: I can manage the space. The only issue using urldecode is that this going in an sql query and I only want to urldecode double quotes and only if they're in this pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
preg_replace('/%22((?:[^%]|%[^2]|%2[^2])*)%22/', '+"$1"', $str);
```

Explanation: The `$1` is a backreference, which references the first `()`-section in the regular expression, in this case, `((?:[^%]|%[^2]|%2[^2])*)`. And the `[^%]` and the alternations `(...|...|...)` after it prevents `%22` in between from being matched due to greediness. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Lazy_quantification.

I found that technique in a JavaCC example of matching block comments (`/* */`), and I can't find any other webpages explaining it, so here is a cleaner example: To match a block of text between 12345 `12345........12345` with no 12345 in between: `/12345([^1]|1[^2]|12[^3]|123[^4]|1234[^5])*12345/`

Comment: You rock. Thank you, very much. Any chance you could offer an explanation on the solution?

Comment: The `$1` is a backreference, which references the first `()`-section in the regular expression, in this case, `((?:[^%]|%[^2]|%2[^2])*)`. And the `[^%]` thing prevents %22 in between from being matched: prevents greedy matching, greediness is explained in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Lazy_quantification , while the `[^%]` method is explained in  http://shinkirou.org/blog/2010/12/tricky-regular-expression-problems/ (first seen in a JavaCC example)

Comment: @SHiNKiROU Explanation to a code given in answer, should be put to **answer itsef**, not to the comments, where many people may miss it. I wonder, why didn't you edit your own answer, when asked for a clarification, and used tiny comment instead?

Answer (score 2):

Seems your data is URL encoded. If you apply [`urldecode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php), you will get

```
"first set" "second set" -drupal -wordpress
```

(I assume you have a space before `-drupal`).

Now you have to add `+`. Again, I assume you have to add those before all words that don't have a `-` and that are not inside quotes:

```
$str = '"first set" "second set" -drupal -wordpress foo';
echo preg_replace('#( |^)(?!(?:\w+"|-| ))#','\1+', $str));
// prints +"first set" +"second set" -drupal -wordpress +foo
```

**Update:** If you cannot use `urldecode`, you could just use `str_replace` to replace `%22` with `"`.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
<?php
  $input = "%22first set%22 %22second set%22-drupal -wordpress";
  $res = preg_replace( "/\%22(.+?)\%22/","+\"(\\1)\" ", $input);
  print $res;
?>
```

Comment: Explanation: the \%22 match "%22". The key here is the (.+?) part, which finds the shortest (i.e., "ungreedy") match between the %22s. In the second part, \1 represents the matched value in (.+?).