# Replace Spaces within "", preg_replace php

Tags: php, preg-replace, pcre

I have some strings like this:

> i: 11;a:5: {s:2:"id";s:4:"1097";s:5:"iName";s:12:"Ovo de Andre";s:10:"dropChance";s:4:"2000";s:4:"type"; i:1;s:5: "kName"; s:12: "Ovo de Andre";

And, I'd like to know how I could replace that string: "Ovo de Andre" to something like this:

> "Ovo_de_Andre", but it can't change any spaces that could be out "".

I tried:

> *$string = preg_replace('/"(.*?)\s(.*?)"/m', '"$1_$2"', $string);*

But it just replaces the first space, then the string looks like this:

> i: 11;a:5: {s:2:"id";s:4:"1097";s:5:"iName";s:12:"Ovo_de Andre";s:10:"dropChance";s:4:"2000";s:4:"type"; i:1;s:5: "kName"; s:12: "Ovo_de Andre";

I know I could use a while to check it, but it'd be problematic to performance and I think it'd would be redundant.

Additionally, I want to know how could it be to make the same, but rather than replacing spaces within "", replace those out, without change spaces within "".

Thanks in advance.

---

I have this link that makes something similar but I couldn't manage what changing to make it reach what i want:
[Using preg_replace to replace all occurrences in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643442/using-preg-replace-to-replace-all-occurrences-in-php).

Here is the full data, I separeted it in strings to test one by one looking for errors that were there.

> > $string = 'a:16:{';
> >         $string .= ' i:0;a:5:{s:2:"id";s:4:"1113";s:5:"iName";s:5:"Drops";s:10:"dropChance";s:4:"7500";s:4:"type";i:1;s:5:"kName";s:5:"Drops";}';
> >         $string .= 'i:1;a:5:{s:2:"id";s:4:"1585";s:5:"iName";s:11:"Mime Monkey";s:10:"dropChance";s:4:"7000";s:4:"type";i:1;s:5:"kName";s:11:"Mime Monkey";}';
> >         $string .= 'i:2;a:5:{s:2:"id";s:4:"1027";s:5:"iName";s:7:"Raptice";s:10:"dropChance";s:4:"7000";s:4:"type";i:1;s:5:"kName";s:7:"Raptice";}';
> >         $string .= 'i:3;a:5:{s:2:"id";s:4:"1002";s:5:"iName";s:6:"Poring";s:10:"dropChance";s:4:"7000";s:4:"type";i:1;s:5:"kName";s:6:"Poring";}';
> >         $string .= 'i:4;a:5:{s:2:"id";s:4:"1767";s:5:"iName";s:8:"Deviling";s:10:"dropChance";s:4:"5000";s:4:"type";i:2;s:5:"kName";s:8:"Deviling";}';
> >         $string .= 'i:5;a:5:{s:2:"id";s:4:"1767";s:5:"iName";s:8:"Deviling";s:10:"dropChance";s:4:"5000";s:4:"type";i:2;s:5:"kName";s:8:"Deviling";}';
> >         $string .= 'i:6;a:5:{s:2:"id";s:4:"1766";s:5:"iName";s:8:"Angeling";s:10:"dropChance";s:4:"5000";s:4:"type";i:2;s:5:"kName";s:8:"Angeling";}';
> >         $string .= 'i:7;a:5:{s:2:"id";s:4:"1766";s:5:"iName";s:8:"Angeling";s:10:"dropChance";s:4:"5000";s:4:"type";i:2;s:5:"kName";s:8:"Angeling";}';
> >         $string .= 'i:8;a:5:{s:2:"id";s:4:"1004";s:5:"iName";s:6:"Zangão";s:10:"dropChance";s:4:"3500";s:4:"type";i:1;s:5:"kName";s:6:"Zangão";}';
> >         $string .= 'i:9;a:5:{s:2:"id";s:4:"1236";s:5:"iName";s:12:"Ovo de Andre";s:10:"dropChance";s:4:"3000";s:4:"type";i:1;s:5:"kName";s:12:"Ovo de Andre";}';
> >         $string .= 'i:10;a:5:{s:2:"id";s:4:"1076";s:5:"iName";s:9:"Esqueleto";s:10:"dropChance";s:4:"3000";s:4:"type";i:1;s:5:"kName";s:9:"Esqueleto";}';
> >         $string .= 'i:11 ;a:5: {s:2:"id";s:4:"1097";s:5:"iName";s:12:"Ovo de Andre";s:10:"dropChance";s:4:"2000";s:4:"type";i:1;s:5:"kName";s:12:"Ovo de Andre";}';
> >         $string .= 'i:12;a:5:{s:2:"id";s:4:"1051";s:5:"iName";s:14:"Besouro-Ladrão";s:10:"dropChance";s:4:"2000";s:4:"type";i:1;s:5:"kName";s:14:"Besouro-Ladrão";}';
> >         $string .= 'i:13;a:5:{s:2:"id";s:4:"1183";s:5:"iName";s:16:"ChonChon Raivoso";s:10:"dropChance";s:4:"1500";s:4:"type";i:1;s:5:"kName";s:16:"ChonChon Raivoso";}';
> >         $string .= 'i:14;a:5:{s:2:"id";s:4:"1011";s:5:"iName";s:8:"ChonChon";s:10:"dropChance";s:4:"1500";s:4:"type";i:1;s:5:"kName";s:8:"ChonChon";}'; 
> >         $string .= 'i:15;a:5:{s:2:"id";s:4:"1784";s:5:"iName";s:5:"Stapo";s:10:"dropChance";s:4:"1000";s:4:"type";i:1;s:5:"kName";s:5:"Stapo";}';
> >         $string .= '}';

If looked carefully you'll notice in the lines i:0 and i:11 of the vector some spaces between the data that shows what line number and size of data exists.

Comment: This looks like a serialized array, why don't you deserialize it first? Anyways, if you just want to replace spaces, then there is not need for a regular expression. Have a look at [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php).

Comment: str_replace would replace spaces out of "" so it would break this string, as it's not a perfect serialized one, this function I'm asking for would remove spaces that are out of true serialized strings to make it a correct serialized one.

Comment: Ok @Marcelo - I see here you have clarified that you don't have a valid serialized object. Disregard my answer then!

Comment: @kissmyface seems to me though, that it would be much simpler to *turn this into* a valid serialized object than to use some convoluted regular expression

Comment: @andrewtweber If you mean modifying the string to add to it what it needs in order to become a valid serialized object then I would tend to agree with you. However without seeing the raw data I can't make that call - there might not be a standard way to do that across all values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
$str = <<< EOF
i: 11;a:5: {s:2:"id";s:4:"1097";s:5:"iName";s:12:"Ovo de Andre";s:10:"dropChance";s:4:"2000";s:4:"type"; i:1;s:5: "kName"; s:12: "Ovo de Andre"
EOF;
$str = preg_replace_callback('#("[^"]*")#',
       create_function('$m',
          'return str_replace(" ", "_", $m[1]);'),
       $str);
echo $str . "\n";
```

**Update:** Since OP likes to have this replacement with single regex only, here is one using negative lookahead:

```
$str = preg_replace('#\s(?!([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)#', '_', $str);
echo $str . "\n";
```

**In short** this regex finds a space which is **NOT** followed by even number of double quotes, which means found space is within double quotes hence it is replaced by under-score.

**OUTPUT:**

```
i: 11;a:5: {s:2:"id";s:4:"1097";s:5:"iName";s:12:"Ovo_de_Andre";s:10:"dropChance";s:4:"2000";s:4:"type"; i:1;s:5: "kName"; s:12: "Ovo_de_Andre"
```

Comment: It worked like a charm, thanks, but I whish it could be a way where I don't need callback to do it.
Just like in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643442/using-preg-replace-to-replace-all-occurrences-in-php

Comment: IMO if something can be achieved with a simple and maintainable code then why strive for complicated solution. There is reason why you haven't got any answer here doing it in straight preg_replace call and there is a reason why PHP dev team came up with `preg_replace_callback`. This is the case where preg_replace_callback should be used. btw I have already upvoted your question so can't up vote again :)

Comment: @Marcelo: Pls see my Update for single regex based solution.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit: OP has clarified that the string is not a valid serialized object...**

I'm not sure if you will be manipulating this object further, or where it came from, but the first thing I would do if it was me is unserialize it (this is making the assumption that you have a serialised object there: it certainly looks like it, although the exact string you posted is not a valid serialized object. I'm making the assumption that you didn't post the whole string).

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php

Once you have your array in a sensible format you can start applying your transformations on a  per attribute basis...

```
//unserialize
$person = unserialize($yourstring);

// now perfrom transformations
$person['iName'] = str_replace(' ', '_', $person['iName']);
$person['kName'] = str_replace(' ', '_', $person['kName']);
// etc...

// now re-serialize 
$person = serialize($person);
```

Performing masses of transformation on attributes of an object/array using regex is just a nightmare - make it easy on yourself and use php native functionality to help you!

If you *dont* have a serialised object then disregard this answer.

Comment: This would not fit as it's not a perfect serialized object.

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid using regex if possible, because you can easily unserialize and read the value, then serialize it back. This will ensure that you know exactly what you're changing.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php

```
function space_to_underscore($str) {
    return str_replace(' ', '_', $str);
}
```

Comment: I can't unserialize because it has spaces between data-key that specifies how much data there is and where the value begins.